# $F_X(x)+F_Y(y)-1\le F_{X,Y}(x,y)\le \sqrt{F_X(x)F_Y(y)}$

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ be the joint probability distribution of the random vector $(X,Y)$; $F_X(x)$ , $F_Y(y)$ the marginal distributions Prove that for all $x,y\in \mathbb R$:

$$F_X(x)+F_Y(y)-1\le F_{X,Y}(x,y)\le \sqrt{F_X(x)F_Y(y)}$$

I know that $F_X(x)\le 1$, $F_Y(y)\le 1$ and $F_{X,Y}(x,y) \le 1$ so $F_X(x)+F_Y(y)-1\le 1$ but that doesn´t mean that $F_X(x)+F_Y(y)-1\le F_{X,Y}(x,y)$

So I would really appreciate if you ca help me with this problem. Any comment, suggestion would be highly appreciated

Comment: $F_{X,Y}(x,y)+F_{X,Y}(\infty,\infty)-F_{X,Y}(x,\infty)-F_{X,Y}(\infty,y)=P(rectangle)\ge 0$. Also $F_X(x)F_Y(y)=(F_{X,Y}(x,y)+A)(F_{X,Y}(x,y)+B)\ge F_{X,Y}^2(x,y)$ where $A,B$ are probabilities of rectangles and hence non-negative.

Comment: This is the elementary inequality $P(A)+P(B)-1\le P(A \cap B)\le \sqrt{P(A)P(B)}$ for events $A=\{X\le x\}$ and $B=\{Y\le y\}$.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of probabilities/expectations:

\begin{align*}
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=&\mathsf{P}(\{X\le x\} \cap \{Y\le y\})\\
=&\mathsf{P}(X\le x)+\mathsf{P}(Y\le y)-\mathsf{P}(\{X\le x\} \cup \{Y\le y\})\\
\ge &\mathsf{P}(X\le x)+\mathsf{P}(Y\le y)-1=F_X(x)+F_Y(y)-1,
\end{align*}

and (by Cauchy-Schwarz)

\begin{align*}
F_{X,Y}(x,y)=&\mathsf{E}1\{X\le x\}1\{Y\le y\} \\
\le &\sqrt{\mathsf{E}[1\{X\le x\}]^2\mathsf{E}[1\{Y\le y\}]^2}=\sqrt{F_X(x)F_Y(y)}.
\end{align*}